# My edittext boxes are all disappeared

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

"I am writing long texts on my table but they just won't wrap, please help, my first textview on the first tablerow is the problem
i am using eclipse and it still can't wrap on the editorview"

i have solved my last problem but found another, all of my edittext boxes are all gone, please help me how to solve it
Here's my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Halaman ini hanya sebagai ilustrasi semata, bukan perhitungan yang pasti, ketentuan dapat berubah sewaktu-waktu sesuai dengan pola kebijakan yang berlaku"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="false"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Jumlah Pinjaman : "/>
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jumlahpinjaman"
        android:layout_span="3"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Jasa Per Tahun : "/>
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jasa"
        android:layout_span="3"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Jangka Waktu : "/>
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jangkawaktu"
        android:layout_span="3"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:text="Perhitungan Jasa : "/>
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/jenisjasa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_span="3"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: try `maxLength` in textview

Comment: Add width and height attribute to editText ..Your problem  will be solved.. these attributes are necessary..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in XML -

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <TableLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="1"
                    >
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                        android:text="Halaman ini hanya sebagai ilustrasi semata, bukan perhitungan yang pasti, 
                        ketentuan dapat berubah sewaktu-waktu sesuai dengan pola kebijakan yang berlaku"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="none"
                        android:singleLine="false"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                        android:text="Jumlah Pinjaman : "
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                        <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/jumlahpinjaman"
                        android:layout_span="3"
 android:hint="Enter value"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                        android:text="Jasa Per Tahun : "
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                        <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/jasa"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_span="3"
 android:hint="Enter value"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                        android:text="Jangka Waktu : "/>
                        <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/jangkawaktu"
                        android:layout_span="3"
 android:hint="Enter value"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                        android:text="Perhitungan Jasa : "
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                        <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/jenisjasa"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_span="3"/>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
```

Hope this code helps you!!!

If its not working please let me know i will try to help you more.

Comment: How your answer help in solving current issue.

Comment: this works but why all my EditText boxes are all gone?

Comment: @user3488298 now please check my edit answer again. and try that code.

Comment: still, my edittext boxes are all gone, why is that? @shweta_jain

Comment: @shweta_jain there i have edited to my latest xml code

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
        android:text="Halaman ini hanya sebagai ilustrasi semata, bukan perhitungan yang pasti, 
        ketentuan dapat berubah sewaktu-waktu sesuai dengan pola kebijakan yang berlaku"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="false"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear user use width and height both wrap content and don't break the text in new.

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Halaman ini hanya sebagai ilustrasi semata, bukan perhitungan yang pasti, ketentuan dapat berubah sewaktu-waktu sesuai dengan pola kebijakan yang berlaku" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` **property** to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

be sure to add minLines and maxLines, so that textview knows how much space to reserve.

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
    android:text="Halaman ini hanya sebagai ilustrasi semata, bukan perhitungan yang pasti, ketentuan dapat berubah sewaktu-waktu sesuai dengan pola kebijakan yang berlaku"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:singleLine="false"/>
</TableRow>
```

credit to: http://droidista.blogspot.com/2010/11/textview-and-maxlines.html